# Copy multiple images to clipboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt6

I have multiple JPG files in a folder. I want to copy all of them to clipboard in one go, so when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> I can paste them.

Shutil will copy and past files from dict to dict:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui

for _ in range(10):
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication([])
    data = QtCore.QMimeData()
    url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(full_file_name)
    data.setUrls([url])
    app.clipboard().setMimeData(data)
```

This code will only copy one random image to the clipboard from the path I set. If I loop through all the files it crashes.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"? Did it throw an error and stop? Or did it just do nothing at all? Or did it stop the program?

Comment: it copy the first images than say canot be a nonetype
when i use if type(data) != None:
it closes all the code suddenly with error 0xc0000005

Comment: What says cannot be a NoneType. Can you paste the entire traceback into your question?

Comment: i uploaded an image of the code and error

Comment: my os : windows

Comment: but it copy one image and i can past it but than crashes like shown in the pics ... want it to coppy all images

Comment: @AkaliDZ The problem is not copying images but it seems that Qt has problems creating (or accessing) the native clipboard. Please use `@username`. You can provide a real [MRE] since by analyzing the image I can see that it is part of a more complex code that could be the cause of the error.

Comment: @AkaliDZ We cannot give you any alternative if you do not provide an MRE, if you do not provide it then I will vote to close your post since it is not reproducible.

Comment: @eyllanesc i opned a new python file and test this particular part of the code and it shows the same error .
i wonder if there is a way to seperate urls and use them like this
 data.setUrls([url], [url2], [url3]...etc)

Comment: @AkaliDZ Show the error message as text and match your new code as I don't believe you.

Comment: @eyllanesc uploaded in the main topic

Comment: @AkaliDZ move `app = QtGui.QGuiApplication([])` before for loop

Comment: @eyllanesc it doesnt show any erros but it only keeps the last elemnt in the clipord

Comment: @AkaliDZ Try my answer

Comment: @eyllanesc i know that the answer is here : data.setUrls([url, url1, url2, url3]) 
but how can i get evry url alone from the loop

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you very much it works like magic ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of the OP (shown in the image) is that he is creating several QGuiApplications and that cannot be done since it is a singleton.

The solution is to create a QGuiAplication before the for loop and then access through the static method `QGuiApplication.clipboard()`:

```py
import os

from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui

path = os.getcwd()

urls = []

it = QtCore.QDirIterator(path, ("*.jpg",), QtCore.QDir.Filters.Files)

while it.hasNext():
    url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(it.next())
    urls.append(url)

if QtGui.QGuiApplication.instance() is None:
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication([])

data = QtCore.QMimeData()
data.setUrls(urls)
QtGui.QGuiApplication.clipboard().setMimeData(data)
```